# How can I compare data from two maps

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I tried comparing data from each table from my data base but i failed
I'm not too familiar with react, I'm still working on it, I'm trying to compare the data from recommendation and customization and if they are the same I display them.

```
  const getRecommendation = () => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:5000/recommendations").then((response) => {
      setRecomList(response.data);
    });
  };
  const getCostumization = () => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:5000/customizations").then((response) => {
      setCustomList(response.data);
    });
  };
  const getRecById = async (id) => {
    Axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/recommendations/${id}`).then((res) => {
      setRecById(
        recById.filter((val) => {
          return val._id === id;
        })
      );
    });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    {
      recommendation.map((rec, i) => {
        customization.map((cus, j) => {
          if (
            rec.type === cus.type &&
            rec.violonBody === cus.violonBody &&
            rec.violonStick === cus.violonStick &&
            rec.violonChincrest === cus.violonChincrest
          ) {
            getCostumization();
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like below

```js
const compare = (obj1, obj2) => {
  const keys1 = Object.keys(obj1);
  const keys2 = Object.keys(obj2);
  if (keys1.length !== keys2.length) return false;
  return keys1.every((key) => obj1[key] === obj2[key]);
};

console.log(compare({ a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 1, b: 2}));
console.log(compare({ a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 1, b: 2, c:3 }));
```

Comment: I tried this one, but i couldn't pass in my data, it keeps saying null

Comment: Should apply `compare` to nested objects

Answer (score 0):

Comparing objects & array is not an easy task to do by ourselves since it involves doing [deep comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness).

One of the popular and convenient way is to use the [_.isEqual](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual) from the [lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash) library.

You could use it like this:

```js
var object = { 'a': 1 };
var other = { 'a': 1 };
 
_.isEqual(object, other);
// => true
 
object === other;
// => false
```

Comment: I did try this one, but sadly it didn't work for me :(

Comment: Could you describe the way it does not work? Did you console log the result?

Comment: At the start it said _ is undefined then i did import lodash, but after i console log the result again it shows nothing

Comment: By showing nothing, do you mean the console.log was not executed? or it showed empty string ("") or undefined? This infromation is important to debug.

Anyway, did you try to console log `recommendation` and `customization` respectively?

Comment: the console.log wasnot executed, i found another solution, i actually just made the changes in the backend part, Thank you for your help!

Comment: Nice, you are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like this? This should return an array of objects that are found in both arrays:

```js
function compareArrays(arr1, arr2) {
  const same = [];

  for (const i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    for (const j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
      if (arr1[i].name === arr2[j].name) {
        same.push(arr1[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  return same;
}
```

So using your example it would look like this:

```js
const getRecommendation = () => {
  Axios.get("http://localhost:5000/recommendations").then((response) => {
    setRecomList(response.data);
  });
};

const getCostumization = () => {
  Axios.get("http://localhost:5000/customizations").then((response) => {
    setCustomList(response.data);
  });
};

const getRecById = async (id) => {
  Axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/recommendations/${id}`).then((res) => {
    setRecById(
      recById.filter((val) => {
        return val._id === id;
      })
    );
  });
};

useEffect(() => {
    const equalPairArray = compareArrays(recommendation, customization)
    if(equalPairArray.length > 0){ 
        getCostumization();
    }
});
```

Comment: I just tried it but i still get nothing